# ErrorDocument in htaccess not working

Tags: .htaccess, errordocument

I'm trying to implement default error page if any internal server error occurs.I went through many articles and question regarding this.But I'm not able to get custom error page.

My .htacess file:

```
DirectoryIndex app.php

ErrorDocument 404 "Ooops...missing something"
ErrorDocument 500 "Ooops...server crashed?"
ErrorDocument 403 "Ooops.Authentication required?"
ErrorDocument 401 "Ooops...secret"

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

  #  ErrorDocument 404 "Ooops...missing something"
   # ErrorDocument 500 "Ooops...server crashed?"
    #ErrorDocument 403 "Ooops.Authentication required?"
   # ErrorDocument 401 "Ooops...secret"

       RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.   
       RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !(.*)api(.*) 
       RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

As refered other question, I checked mod rewrite and it works to move non-www to www .You can see above rewrite rule.

But `errordoument` not working.I tried to place `error document` in different places also Is I'm placing `errordoument` in wrong place?

I'm referring [this](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/custom-error.html) document.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What is not working?

Comment: custom page not displaying.for testing I used message. which is not displaying...It is displaying 500 internal server error only

Comment: Ok check your Apache's `error.log` for reason of this 500 error.

Comment: I want to display custom page for user if any error is unhandled

Comment: Yes got it but since you're getting 500 you need to check Apache error.log and comment out `ErrorDocument 500` line.

Comment: If I comment out ErrorDocument 500 ill get error"Unable to find template "AuthBundle:FacebookAuth:FBCallback.html.twig"." If I'm not comment out also getting same error.But my requirement is I want custom message

Comment: That means you have some directive that is locating `"AuthBundle:FacebookAuth:FBCallback.html.twig"` With `ErrorDocument 500` uncommented what error does error.log show?

Comment: Actually for testing I created some internal error.This question is nothing to do with this error. My question is why I'm not able to get "Ooops, that page was <b>not found</b>. Pleas"

Comment: if I'm entering not existed url say, www.mydomain.com/wsafsdf it will throw 404.That time I want to show custom page

Comment: Remove your error creation because it might be causing error while processing `ErrorDocument` also.

Comment: What I exactly wanted to do is explained in http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/custom-error.html . but something I'm missing

Comment: I have modified above code for better understanding

Comment: Yes all of these `ErrorDocument` work fine for me so you have some other mis-configuration.

Comment: After updating in htaccess anything we need to restart? anything else need to configure?

Comment: You don't need to restart Apache.